# Background-image will not load image Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, background-image

I have implemented this: [animated header](https://codepen.io/nodws/pen/aWgMMQ) in my rails app. Everything works fine but I wanted to change the header image and for some reason it does not load... I have tried the same syntax on a different page for loading the image and it works fine in rails.

**How can I make this work and what am I missing?**

**my changed css code**

```
.header:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  background-image: asset-data-url("header_background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: top center;
  background-color: #1B2030;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  animation: grow 60s linear 10ms infinite;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

**the code from codepen**

```
.header:before{
  content:"";
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  background:#1B2030 url(https://unsplash.it/1999/999?image=1063) top center no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  animation: grow 60s  linear 10ms infinite;
  transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  z-index:-2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have figured it out! I have used the css in the view in script tags this was the reason why it would not load... I guess asset-data-url works only when its implemented in a css file...